# How do I make it so that the "Title" doesn't appear on the screen?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

This is my first time working with anything like Drupal, and I was wondering how to make the title "invisible" or in other words, so that it doesn't show up on the screen. I have some instructions for Drupal 6, but I'm using Drupal 7 and I can't figure out what to do. Help is appreciated!

Here are the instructions for Drupal 6:

[image]

And here's the page I'm trying to make (I don't want the "Invisible Title" to show up on the screen!):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Exclude node title](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) to do that.

I don't know what module are you using, but I think it helps you.

Comment: Ah ok, so is this an add on that I have to install??

Comment: Yes, you have to install it in Modules section. Then you see an option to exclude the node title of the screen. Also you can hide the titles of an entire content type.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you create a content in Drupal you got some fields.
Say your **content type** is an **article** with a **title**,
you can change/add/remove fields under structure -> contenttype -> manage fields
and **you can modify the aspect of that fields under structure -> contenttype -> manage display** hiding the title field

more info here: **https://www.drupal.org/node/1795294**

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Automatic Nodetitles module which supports this option.
Check this here: https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle

Answer (score 0):

Write your own module.

Put hook_form_alter into it and change your $form_state.

Or go to your content type / manage display, find your filed there and hide its title.